# IHS and WAS configuration OK, but can't connect to application via WebServer

Tags: cluster-computing, websphere-7, ibm-was, ibmhttpserver

I've successfully setup IBH HTTP Server, generated the plugin, propagated it from WAS admin console to the remote WebServer, but still cannot connect to the application via the Web Server.

I've followed with success the steps for configuring the HTTP server as stated in IBM manuals [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS9JLE_8.2.1/com.ibm.itamesso.doc_8.2.1/Installation_Guide/tasks/configuring_ihs_wasnd.html).

The WebServer is up on port 880 and I can see the welcome page of IHS from a remote machine when requesting: http://ihs-ip@:880

Requesting: http://ihs-ip@:880/app_name throws a 404 Not Found message, no errors in the log files.

Firewall and SELinux are disabled on the IHS machine.

I tried restarting the webserver, the DMGR and the two cluster app nodes with no success.

WebSphere AS version is: 7.0.0.31 ND

I can post my httpd.conf and plugin-cfg.xml content if needed.

Any clues?

Thanks.

### **UPDATE:**

Here is the content of my plugin-cfg.xml file (I've also noticed that I don't have a *.880 alias in the default_host virtual host):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><!--HTTP server plugin config file for the webserver DmgrBrokerClusterCell.ws-005056878644.xxxxx.com-node.webServerBroker880 generated on 2015.02.06 at 01:00:02 AM CET-->
<Config ASDisableNagle="false" AcceptAllContent="false" AppServerPortPreference="HostHeader" ChunkedResponse="false" FIPSEnable="false" FailoverToNext="false" HTTPMaxHeaders="300" IISDisableFlushFlag="false" IISDisableNagle="false" IISPluginPriority="High" IgnoreDNSFailures="false" KillWebServerStartUpOnParseErr="false" MarkBusyDown="false" OS400ConvertQueryStringToJobCCSID="false" RefreshInterval="60" ResponseChunkSize="64" SSLConsolidate="true" TrustedProxyEnable="false" VHostMatchingCompat="false">
   <Log LogLevel="Error" Name="/opt/IBM/HTTPServer/Plugins/logs/webServerBroker880/http_plugin.log"/>
   <Property Name="ESIEnable" Value="true"/>
   <Property Name="ESIMaxCacheSize" Value="1024"/>
   <Property Name="ESIInvalidationMonitor" Value="false"/>
   <Property Name="ESIEnableToPassCookies" Value="false"/>
   <Property Name="ESICacheidFull" Value="false"/>
   <Property Name="PluginInstallRoot" Value="/opt/IBM/HTTPServer/Plugins/"/>
   <VirtualHostGroup Name="default_host">
      <VirtualHost Name="*:9080"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="*:80"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="*:9443"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="*:5060"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="*:5061"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="*:443"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="ws-005056874449.xxxxx.com:9080"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="ws-005056874449.xxxxx.com:80"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="ws-005056874449.xxxxx.com:9443"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="ws-005056874449.xxxxx.com:5060"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="ws-005056874449.xxxxx.com:5061"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="ws-005056874449.xxxxx.com:443"/>
      <VirtualHost Name="*:9083"/>
   </VirtualHostGroup>
   <ServerCluster CloneSeparatorChange="false" GetDWLMTable="false" IgnoreAffinityRequests="true" LoadBalance="Round Robin" Name="BrokerCluster" PostBufferSize="64" PostSizeLimit="-1" RemoveSpecialHeaders="true" RetryInterval="60" ServerIOTimeoutRetry="-1">
      <Server CloneID="19da3jqec" ConnectTimeout="5" ExtendedHandshake="false" LoadBalanceWeight="2" MaxConnections="-1" Name="BrokerClusterNode001_Broker01" ServerIOTimeout="60" WaitForContinue="false">
         <Transport Hostname="10.1.140.206" Port="9083" Protocol="http"/>
         <Transport Hostname="10.1.140.206" Port="9446" Protocol="https">
            <Property Name="keyring" Value="/opt/IBM/HTTPServer/Plugins/config/webServerBroker880/plugin-key.kdb"/>
            <Property Name="stashfile" Value="/opt/IBM/HTTPServer/Plugins/config/webServerBroker880/plugin-key.sth"/>
         </Transport>
      </Server>
      <Server CloneID="19da3jrkm" ConnectTimeout="5" ExtendedHandshake="false" LoadBalanceWeight="2" MaxConnections="-1" Name="BrokerClusterNode002_Broker02" ServerIOTimeout="60" WaitForContinue="false">
         <Transport Hostname="10.1.140.207" Port="9083" Protocol="http"/>
         <Transport Hostname="10.1.140.207" Port="9446" Protocol="https">
            <Property Name="keyring" Value="/opt/IBM/HTTPServer/Plugins/config/webServerBroker880/plugin-key.kdb"/>
            <Property Name="stashfile" Value="/opt/IBM/HTTPServer/Plugins/config/webServerBroker880/plugin-key.sth"/>
         </Transport>
      </Server>
      <PrimaryServers>
         <Server Name="BrokerClusterNode001_Broker01"/>
         <Server Name="BrokerClusterNode002_Broker02"/>
      </PrimaryServers>
   </ServerCluster>
   <UriGroup Name="default_host_BrokerCluster_URIs">
      <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/Broker/*"/>
   </UriGroup>
   <Route ServerCluster="BrokerCluster" UriGroup="default_host_BrokerCluster_URIs" VirtualHostGroup="default_host"/>
   <RequestMetrics armEnabled="false" loggingEnabled="false" rmEnabled="false" traceLevel="HOPS">
      <filters enable="false" type="URI">
         <filterValues enable="false" value="/snoop"/>
         <filterValues enable="false" value="/hitcount"/>
      </filters>
      <filters enable="false" type="SOURCE_IP">
         <filterValues enable="false" value="255.255.255.255"/>
         <filterValues enable="false" value="254.254.254.254"/>
      </filters>
      <filters enable="false" type="JMS">
         <filterValues enable="false" value="destination=aaa"/>
      </filters>
      <filters enable="false" type="WEB_SERVICES">
         <filterValues enable="false" value="wsdlPort=aaa:op=bbb:nameSpace=ccc"/>
      </filters>
   </RequestMetrics>
</Config>
```

Comment: Post your `plugin-cfg.xml`, as probably either your application is not mapped to the web server (e.g. via console), plugin conf is not regenerated, or you dont have *:880 alias in the default_host virtual host.

Comment: Updated with the plugin-cfg.xml file. Thanks.

Comment: Just noticed I've updated with an incomplete plugin-cfg.xml file. Re-updated with the good one.

Comment: Looks like your application is `Name="/Broker/*`. But as you noticed, you dont have 880 alias, so you need to fix that (create alias and regen plugin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the port your client addresses the webserver via (880) to the default_host host alias in WAS for it to be recognized as associated with the application. Then generate and propagate plugin-cfg.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should begin healcheck file `plugin-cfg.xml` in folder `/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Plugins/config/http30WebSrv1`
Because you Generate Plug-in maybe have error

```
InformationPLGC0063E: The propagation of the plug-in configuration file from /u01/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Dmgr01/config/cells/tpxCell01/nodes/tpx04IHSNode01/servers/trn03WebSrv011/plugin-cfg.xml to /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Plugins/config/trn03WebSrv011/plugin-cfg.xml on the Web server computer failed.
```

So you can add permission for folder:

```
chown -R ihsuser:ihsgroup /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Plugins/config/trn03WebSrv011/
```

and generate Plug-in and Propagate Plug-in

Thanks and regards

tandn